# How to block an order by country?

Tags: checkout, sales-order, countries

I currently authorized in the administration five countries but I would want to keep one, so I just chose this country in configuration> General> countries Options> allow countries.

The problem is that for older customers who have already registered their addresses, are not blocked when ordering, it works only for new customers.

How can I block old customers?

Answer (score 0):

You can usually enable/disable payment and shipping methods by country as well. Existing customers won't be able to checkout if there are no payment or shipping methods available for their country.

Comment: i use payement cb via ogone but in configuration, there is no choice for state.do you know a solution?